# When trying to use GetPrivateConversationData I get: Security token for MicrosoftAppId: is unauthorized to post to connector

Tags: botframework

When I try using this code:

```
                StateClient sc = new StateClient(new Microsoft.Bot.Connector.MicrosoftAppCredentials());
            BotData userData;
            try
            {
                userData = sc.BotState.GetPrivateConversationData(activity.ChannelId, activity.Conversation.Id, activity.From.Id);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw;
            }
```

I get this error:

"Security token for MicrosoftAppId:  is unauthorized to post to connector!"

I am trying to follow the directions here:
http://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/stateapi.html#contextualproperties

but that code simply wont compile. The method signatures are incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code appears to work:

```
                StateClient sc = activity.GetStateClient();
            BotData userData = sc.BotState.GetPrivateConversationData(activity.ChannelId, activity.Conversation.Id, activity.From.Id);
```